Identify the open tag file
I have set :set tags=./tags;$HOME to do an "upward search" for a tags file. How do I find out what file has actually been loaded?

Reading :help 'tags' and scrolling a little bit down finds the following sentence:
The tagfiles() function can be used to get a list of the file names
actually used.

Accordingly, :echo tagfiles() will show the name(s) of found tagfile(s).
An easy way to test this is in any of Vim's help files.
It will pick up the helptags in <whatever>/doc/tags.

Ok, thanks. To be fair, this is mentioned nowhere in the reference page for tags.

I admit it took me amazingly long to find it.

It is mentioned under the relevant doc: :help 'tags'.

... and that's where I found it... after looking everywhere else :-D

echo findfile("tags", "./;$HOME") appears to work, but it is slightly different syntax and redoes the search.
